# Apex chart (Dynamic loaded) chart implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

i'am trying to replicate the following graph using react using this amazing library called apex charts
https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/dynamic-loaded-chart/

by using the code given in that website 
yearSeries.data[selectedIndex].quarters is an undefined value for me. Can anyone tell me what kind of data is this graph taking as an input

there's this makeData() which is getting called there can anyone tell me the return value of it

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of ApexCharts here, the example you linked has an external js file which is not included in the website demo code, sorry about that.

I have just updated the website example and included the missing code on the same page (please do a hard refresh / clear cache to see changes) - https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/dynamic-loaded-chart/

Comment: Thank you for quick reply...but still iám having trouble with ApexCharts.exec
`react_apexcharts__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.exec is not a function`

Comment: I have an immediate requirement to generate apex charts using AngularJS 1. Is it possible using ng-apex charts. Could I get a demo in plunker. Also I need a to generate pdf of the graph.

Comment: Unfortunately in the link the code is still not showing all the code. Could you fix that? @junedchhipa